# How to mirror the image on Cheese application on Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, cheese

I'm new to Ubuntu. I have discovered that Ubuntu has a built-in webcam application called Cheese. It's doing its job but I want my images to be mirrored. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if the developers of Cheese have done any user research on how to best name the effects. Personally, I have never thought, while looking in the mirror, hey, the mirror seems to "flip" the image of myself. The existence of this Question might indicate that Mirror would be a more usable name of the effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open Cheese, click on Effects, and choose Flip.

Comment: not worked. the flipped image is the same as non-flipped.
# Thinkpad x1nano, cheese 43.0-1

Comment: I get the same as @Lenik; I just noticed after some trial and error that if I click "flip" and then click "no effect" *then* the "flip" takes effect.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯